# Conditional searches on pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter a Pandas dataframe. The format of the data is a block of data with whitespace in between.

```
data1, data2

val1,  val2
val1,  val2

val1,  val2
```

I want to filter the blocks but keep the whitespace in the dataframe. My code that should do this is:

```
df = df.loc[(df['data2'] >= threshold) and (df['data2'] == '')]
```

but this returns the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've tried inserting these methods into my line, but nothing seems to work, it's probably my sleeop-deprived brain but if anyone

Comment: `and` understands scalar values, you're comparing array-like structures so it barfs because it's ambiguous if you have a single match should it return `True`? the bitwise operators work on the entire array and return an array of boolean values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `and` indeed causes the interpreter to think you're trying to find a boolean value using two types that don't support this. In this case, you're probably looking for `&`:

```
df['data2'] >= threshold) & (df['data2'] == '')
```

---

**Example**

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.array([True, False]) & np.array([True, True])
Out[2]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)

In [3]: np.array([True, False]) and np.array([True, True])
-------------------------------------------------------------------    --------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent     call last)
<ipython-input-3-76eeded6cdad> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([True, False]) and np.array([True, True])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: OK, but changing it to a & gives me a TypeError: invalid type comparison
exception

Comment: @GreenGodot Can you post the output of `df['data2'] >= threshold` and `df['data2'] == ''`?

Comment: Ah, i was doing the comaprison with the empty string wrong. I should have just called isnull() instead, that fixed the issue.